# meaning: do something together

Tags: adverbs

Does the following sentence make sense? This doesn't seem be a grammar question.

> Neither John nor I am having dinner together.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. 'Neither' is used about each one of two things considered individually, and 'together' is used about more than one thing, considered jointly. You could say "John and I are not having dinner together (or with each other)", or "Neither John nor I is dining with the other".

Comment: I wonder why you do this. You ask grammatical questions that make no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense. 'Neither' is used about each one of two things considered individually, and 'together' is used about more than one thing, considered jointly. You could say "John and I are not having dinner together (or with each other)", or "Neither John nor I is dining with the other".

> neither
>   determiner, pronoun, conjunction, adverb
>
> not either of two things or people

[Neither (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/neither)

> together
>   adverb
>
> with each other

[Together (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/together)